# MySQL: could not get mysqldump version

Tags: server, 18.04, mysql, backup, mysql-workbench

I use MySQL workbench 6.3 on Ubunut 18 using MySQL server 8+. 
I need to backup my database from the workbench. When I click on `Data export` I select the scheme and make sure all the tables needed are checked. I choose the file path where I want to export the backup (external hard drive). I click `export` but I get error saying:

> Could not get mysqldump version Workbench was unable to get mysqldump
>   version. Please verify the log for more information

Please note that I first get warning syaing the existing data will be overwritten (I deleted old backup but I am saving the new one under same name). Although the old files are not there, I click ok. But still the backup does not work in both types (self-contained sql file or dump project files).

How to solve the issue?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644697/mysqlworkbench-giving-version-error-on-exporting-database/45141537) have similar problem. It suggest going to `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Administration` and to change the `path to mysqldump tool` to where mysqldump is. I tried to change it to both:
/usr/bin/mysqldump
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysqldump

After each change, I close and open the MySQL workbench. Nothing solve the issue.

Note, this is the result for locating `mysqldump`.

```
$ locate mysqldump
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
/usr/bin/mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldumpslow
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysqldump
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldumpslow.1.gz
```

Please note that the export worked with me yesterday. I did not change anything apart from shutting down my device and start it.

Please note that I also upgraded both MySQL workbench and MySQL server. I did not remove the old MySQL server but when I check the version using:  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` 
It see the new version: 8.0.15

Here is the MySQL workbench paths I see:

[image]

Also, when I go to `/usr/bin/` and execute: `mysqldump --version` I get:

```
mysqldump: [Warning] unknown variable 'loose-local-infile=1'.
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.15 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Finally, the `loose-local-infile=1` is an entry I entered in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to be able to load data from local files into my database.

Please, help me solve my problem. I need to backup my databases to do some changes.

Comment: Is there a `loose-local-infile` parameter somewhere in your `my.cnf`?

Comment: Yes. See the last three lines in my post. In my.cnf these 3 lines there: `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[client]
loose-local-infile=1` The last two (starting from [client]) I added them manually to allow me load data from files into my tables.

Comment: Parameters that start with `loose-` should be ignored by programs that do not understand them. They should not throw a "unknown variable" warning. Anyway, I would comment out the line first, make a backup, and then uncomment the line while we find out what is going on.

Comment: I removed that line completely. I found it in `my.cnf` anf in `mysql.cnf`. I may have added it to `mysql.cnf` previously by mistake. Can you confirm to me that it should not exist in `mysql.cnf`? Anyways, even after removing that line from both files, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and in my case solved it in another way.
Try this:

**Open your Console:**

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p <data_base_name> > /home/<user>/<did>/database-dump.sql
```

For example:

```
mysqldump -u root -p wp_site > /home/victor_santos/Desktop/database-dump.sql
```

After there, press *Enter* and enter user password.

> OBS: User must have permission to access and export data from this
>   database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with MySQL workbench 6.3 version. When I removed it, and installed the newer version MySQL workbench 8, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Nope, same issue

Comment: Same issue here with the latest version as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was related to `.my.cnf` file under `/home/user/` because when the Workbench was trying to get to the specifics of the file, it had been overwritten (by some other app which uses same configuration).

Run 
`mysqldump --version`
and if it says :
 `mysqldump: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /home/user/.my.cnf at line X!` 
then you can just rename the .my.cnf file with app_.my.cnf for later usage.

Run Workbench - it should work.

Answer (score 0):

After running:

```
sudo apt install mysql-client-5.7
```

Restart MySQL workbench and re-try the export. It will work now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the permissions on the `/etc/my.cnf` file.
If you run `mysql --version` in a console, it gives the warning:

```
World-writable config file /etc/my.cnf is ignored
```

**What you have to do is change the permissions of that file:**

```bsh
sudo chmod 644 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

Fixing the permissions should stop the warning from appearing.